# Trackpad gets stuck in select mode

Tags: hardware, macbook-pro, trackpad

I'm experiencing the problems 
[described here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3741448?start=0&tstart=0), basically the trackpad has spurts of spurious input, but the problems are fairly intermittent.  I've kept the system usable by deactivating many non-critical gestures, like zooming, three finger drag, etc.

Are there any visualization or tuning tools for the Mac Book Air's trackpad?  It'd be useful to simply get a graphical record of the trackpad's input over a period when it was miss-behaving.

Are there any such tools under Linux if not under Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to see what your trackpad "sees", you can use [FingerMgmt](http://blog.sendapatch.se/2009/november/multitouch-on-unibody-macbooks.html).

As for your problem, do you have tap-to-click on? If so, does turning it off solve the problem?

Comment: I'm trying that now since finding the thread I linked.  An Apple tech suggested switching hands and resting one on one side of the case, suggested there is a ground connecter there that occasionally comes loose.  Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, FingerMgmt has ocasional crashes when running under the Trackpad, but not under Magic Mouse.  If it's actually related, maybe that'll give some information.  Thanks again!